# "All of a sudden" vs. "all of the sudden"

Tags: expressions

According to Google (63 million results), it should be *all of the sudden*, though, 22 million results say otherwise, which one is correct?

Comment: First, Google results numbers are extremely unreliable. Second, try searching with quotes around the phrase and you'll find a different story (I got 11 million for "a sudden" and 6 million for "the sudden").

Comment: And third, I have seen the word "sudden" too much in a short time span and it has now lost all meaning for me. I hate it when that happens.

Comment: perhaps "suddenly" is a better option?

Comment: I don't believe this should be categorized as off-topic.  Google brought me here as the first search result for "all of a sudden vs all of the sudden," so it seems english.stackexchange has become the de facto reference.

Comment: @Eric But no valid reference is included to support the claim. Start another question including true data and dictionary references.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"All of **a** sudden" is [the idiom](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20of%20a%20sudden). I rationalize that there is no particular *sudden*, so it has to be *a* sudden.

[Brians Common Errors](http://www.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/sudden.html) backs me up here, although idioms don't necessarily follow the rules of grammar anyway.

Comment: Hahah - I've used "the sudden" all my life. I'd use your same argument to justify that it is better. It IS a particular sudden. All of the sudden something happened. All of a different sudden something else happened. The one I'm talking about when I use the phrase is a particular one.

Comment: I thought that was a typo for "Brian's Common Errors", but, on seeing that it is the site of Paul Brians, I now suspect that it should be "Brians's Common Errors" (or "Brians' Common Errors", if you do that).  But then it sounds like those are common errors by Brians.  Hmm.

Answer (score 4):

Each one of those 63 million results says that *all of the sudden* doesn't really make any sense.

The idiom

> All of a sudden : very quickly and unexpectedly, suddenly.

A sample sentence would be

> I felt a sharp pain in my side all of a sudden.

Answer (score 2):

I find this:

> If we go back beyond Shakespeare the variant 'the sudden' was commonplace; for example, ...

in [PHRASES.ORG.UK](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/all-of-a-sudden.html)

Comment: I wonder if "a" started to be used more than "the" because "of the" is harder to pronounce than "of a" is, in a similar way to how the "correct" way to pronounce raspberry is razberry.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you say the phrase really quickly, the words get pressed together and it can sound like you are saying 'the' sudden. So that is why people start saying it the wrong way.

Comment: The question is "Which one is correct?" - and Why? Please answer the **question**.

Comment: I was answering the other,much more hidden question: why do 22 million google search results contradict the other 63 million search results? This question, although not spelled out, is inherent to the original question and I must say that no one else took the time out like I did to try to solve it. The solution is this: people slur their words together and so therefore it has created another way of saying the original phrase. And this would be the answer as to why the Google outcome has mixed results. I am glad to have added something new to this conversation. Thank you.

Comment: Then **please** make your answers clearer. Note the the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): **Answer the question** Read the question carefully. *What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that* – or a viable alternative. ... Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, *but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications* in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but ***fuller explanations are better***. Also, please incorporate the additional info into your answer as comments are transient.

Comment: You didn't answer the Question. If you have something to say but you're not answering the Question, you should add a Comment, not an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally *suddenly* expresses exactly the same meaning and is more elegant.

If you must use it, I agree that *all of a sudden* is the correct usage.

Answer (score -1):

It took all of 10 years to build that bridge.  The 10 years is non specific.

If the 10 years was specified previously:  The schedule allowed 10 years to build the bridge, then you could reference it thusly:   It took all of the 10 years to build it.

So,

If your sudden is previously specified, you could reference it as "the sudden":

"The wink of his eye happened in a sudden moment.  All of the sudden the other eye blinked."

Otherwise, the non-specific "a sudden" should be used.

"All of a sudden, it made perfect sense."

Comment: This is logical enough, but idiom trumps logic. “All of the sudden” is simply not the idiom. Then again, logically, when something happens suddenly, the sudden in (or of) which it happens is by definition a new one—you cannot predefine a sudden and then populate it afterwards, except humorously: “All of a sudden, he winked—but he did it so vigorously that _all_ of the sudden was pregnant with his wink”, for example, is possible, but quite strange.

Comment: I was simply backing the correct idiom : )

Comment: A sudden is rarely, if ever, previously specified.

Comment: @Dave, I have never met a previously specified sudden.  Thanks for THIS sudden!